# INSERT INTO table IF table exists otherwise CREATE TABLE

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Do mysql support something like this?

```
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (NULL,"1234") IF TABLE EXISTS `table` ELSE CREATE TABLE `table` (id INT(10), word VARCHAR(500));
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd create 2 statements. Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
id INT(10),
word VARCHAR(500)
);
INSERT INTO `table` VALUES (NULL,"1234");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can first check if the table exists, if it doesn't then you can create it. 
Do the insert statement after this..

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Something like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (...)

INSERT INTO table VALUES (...)
```

Note:

> However, there is no verification that the existing table has a structure identical to that indicated by the CREATE TABLE statement.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't support creating a table in the `SELECT` statement, but you can easily preface with a quick check to create your table if it doesn't exist:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table` (
    id INT(10),
    word VARCHAR(500)
);
```